# What is this form of JavaScript class field definition?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, constructor

I have just come across some code of this form:

```
class Foo {
  someValue = 1;
}
```

This does seem to work natively in the browser, and behaves as if it was:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.someValue = 1;
  }
}
```

But I can't see this form documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes - or perhaps I'm missing something.

Is it exactly equivalent to the constructor version? What standard is it part of?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields

Comment: Ah, public fields. Thank you.

Comment: Still an experimental feature (stage 3), but it would be nice if it goes forward.

Comment: If you write that up as an answer I can accept it.